# Почему PhpStorm выводит две ссылки на один и тот же файл, когда жму Ctrl+клик в коде (всего файл один, а ссылки две)?

Tags: phpstorm

Прикладываю скриншот. Почему так происходит? Как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И скриншот папки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы папку слева открыли ту, где fontello. Скорее всего, там два файла - обычный и минифицированный. Или два файла, у которых буквы одинаковые на вид, но на самом деле разные.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, добавил, посмотрите.